# Getting started with cairo using java bindings on windows

Tags: cairo

I have scourged google and SO for hours together but having no luck, hence posting it here.

I am trying to use cairo graphics library on windows and have the GTK runtime installed. Could 
any one help me write a simple java program in eclipse ide using cairo libraries?.

I will find my way around the api from there ( hopefully :-) )

Thanks ,
Goutham

Answer (score 0):

Do you have GTK 3? From the official documentation, it doesn't seem as if Cairo will be usable with the Java-Windows for some time. Largely, because Cairo has become tied to the GNOME stack, and that is not fully available on Windows. And since the developers all tend to switch from Windows to Linux, they keep on losing their Windows developers...

I'd myself love to use Cairo instead of Batik, but currently Batik seems to be the best usable vector graphics library for all platforms.